# Inserting data in MySQL table only if it doesn't exist already: trouble with INSERT IGNORE

Tags: php, mysql, insert

so I've been looking around StackOverflow and the MySQL manual for a while, and I can't seem to solve my problem. What I'm trying to do is simply make my data INSERT function such that it doesn't add anything to my table if it already exists. I saw a few methods: the INSERT IGNORE function, together with a unique index, was the one that seemed the best for me, but I have no idea why it is not working... Here is a portion of my code (I have two columns: 'username' and 'email', and my table is called 'info4'):

```
$unique_index = mysqli_query ($con, "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index ON info4 ( username, email);");

$insert = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT IGNORE INTO info4 (`username`, `email`) VALUES ('$array_values[0]', '$array_values[1]')");
```

Where am I going wrong? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Insert Ignore` simply tells MySQL to not issue a duplicate key error when trying to insert duplicate data into fields with unique constraints.

The unique index should be all you need to stop duplicate entries from being inserted.

Generally you wouldn't want to do things like add indexes using PHP, you should do that via whatever tool you are using to access your database.

Are you seeing duplicate username/email combos being inserted into your table? What are the values of `$array_values[0]` and `$array_values[1]` ?

If you do `SHOW INDEX FROM info4` do you see your unique index?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I add Insert ignore because I read that it prevents errors from occurring. The values of those variables come from a form. In fact this code is on a process.php page, for an html user form; those values are entered by a user. My problem is that if a user uses the form more than once and enters the same value more than once, it appears in my table more than once, and that is what I'm trying to prevent. And that code at the end doesn't show anything, does that mean my index isn't created?

Comment: @TudorManole where are you entering the SHOW INDEX query?

Answer (score 2):

You can't create an index named index.

Mysql is not case sensitive. Your INDEX wrongly named "index" won't work.

Example:

mysql> create index index on tbladresse (strasse_zusatz);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index
 on tbladresse (strasse_zusatz)' at line 1

mysql> create index iindex on tbladresse (strasse_zusatz);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip, but even after replacing the name of the index, the code doesn't work...

Comment: You're welcome. Although I'm a beginner in mysql and php as well so I think that @TheMethod is more likely to help you out on this. He has got some good info and questions in his post.